# Minute of automatic date & time field doesn't set correctly

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, calculated-column

Into `NewForm.aspx` I have Date and Time field, which I disabled via jQuery.

My computer is set to `14:46`, so I will receive `14:45` in SharePoint. Hour is correct but minutes are not; it is always set as `00`.

### Column Setting

[image: List column settings]

### Field in NewForm.aspx

[image: Field in NewForm.aspx dialog]

### JS to disable date and time column

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     var itemID = $("input[title='Fecha']").attr("id");

// Trim the Item ID and keep the first part which is common for each element of this DatePicker

    var itemCode = itemID.substring(0, itemID.indexOf('$'));

    // Set text input to readOnly  

    $( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dtinput > input[id$='Date']" ).attr('readonly', 'readonly');


    $( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dtinput > input[id$='Date']" ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    // Disable the onclick action on the button

    $( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dtinput > a" ).attr('onclick','').unbind('click');

    // Disable the 2 time select elements

    $( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dttimeinput > select[id$='DateHours']" ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dttimeinput > select[id$='DateMinutes']" ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

});

</script>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you instead use the calculated value default value option, and set it to NOW(), this will set the date, plus hour *and* time. Keep in mind the hour may not match your local time, based on your time zone settings, but I just confirmed the use of now() will set the minute value correctly.

Cheers,
Matt

[image]

Comment: Best solution, I was thinking about set something like DateTime.Now.Utc with javascript, but your solution is the best